# Validation rule get all picklist values

Tags: formula, picklist, validation-rule

How can I get all picklist values in a validation rule?

I'm looking for a suitable function but I cannot find any.

What I need to achieve is that some string is among the picklist values.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such function to get all picklist values. You can enable the "[Strictly Enforce Picklist Values](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_restricted_picklists_beta.htm)" function for a picklist, or use Apex code, but Validation Rules won't get you where you want to go.